# Back/Return button with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I'm very new in Angular and have a problem.

I have page with list of a items (some appointments).

AppointmentsSummary.chtml

```
<div class="border-section">
    <table>
        <thead>
        ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="app in appts">
          <td>
            <a href="#/Appointments/AppointmentsSummary/MessageHistory/{{app.patientId}}">
                 <button type="button">Message history</button>
            </a>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I have a controller for this template:

```
function AppointmentsSummaryController($scope, $location, AppointmentResource) {
 console.log("loaded..");
 $scope.appts = AppointmentResource.getAll({
           .....(params)
        });

}
```

When I clicked on the button "Message history" on the AppointmentsSummary.html - I relocate to page MessageHistiry.html, which has a "Back" button.

```
<a href="#/Appointments/AppointmentsSummary">
    <button type="button">Back</button>
</a>
```

When I push this button, I return to list of appointments and AppointmentsControllerSummary reloaded and $scope.appts becomes null.

For routing between pages I uses $routeProvider (same with below)

```
$routeProvider.when(/Appointments/AppointmentsSummary/MessageHistory/:patientId', {
                        controller:'MessageHistoryController',
                        templateUrl:'Template/MessageHistory',
                        reloadOnSearch: false
```

Can I not reload this controller and save my $scope data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your data in a service. Services are singletons, meaning they always return the same instance and therefore preserve state. Controllers get re-instantiated each time they are loaded and therefore do not preserve state.

```
myApp.factory('MyService', function() {
    var appts = AppointmentResource.getAll({
       .....(params)
    });

    return {
       appts: appts
    };
});
```

Then in your controller, you can just do..

```
$scope.appts = MyService.appts;
```

The appts variable in the service won't get reloaded when you reload controllers and the data will be preserved. From the [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)...

"Lastly, it is important to realize that all Angular services are application singletons. This means that there is only one instance of a given service per injector."

Often when preserving state is the issue, singletons are the solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it works not correct for me. What about params?
I gets list of appointments from DB with AppointmentResource (with $resource provider).
So, params sending to this resource from AppointmentSummary.html scope. And, when I change this $scope, i need reload data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlie Martin for idea with singleton-service.

I create appointmentService

```
.factory('appointmentService', function (AppointmentResource, dateSharedService, doctorSharedService) {

    appointmentService = {};

    appointmentService.reloadAppts = function() {
        appointmentService.appts = AppointmentResource.getAll({
            filterFirstDate: dateSharedService.firstDate,
            filterSecondDate: dateSharedService.secondDate,
            doctorIds: doctorSharedService.doctorIds
        });
    };

    appointmentService.appts = AppointmentResource.getAll({
        filterFirstDate: dateSharedService.firstDate,
        filterSecondDate: dateSharedService.secondDate,
        doctorIds: doctorSharedService.doctorIds
    });

    return appointmentService;
});
```

And, so, this is part of code from my controller:

```
function AppointmentsSummaryController($scope, appointmentService) {
    $scope.appts = appointmentService.appts;

    $scope.$on('firstDateChanges', function () {   
        appointmentService.reloadAppts();
        $scope.appts = appointmentService.appts;
    });

    $scope.$on('secondDateChanges', function () {
        appointmentService.reloadAppts();
        $scope.appts = appointmentService.appts;
    });
    .....
}
```

When I load my controller at first, I get default appointments, which will today.
If params from scope changes - appointmentService get it from another injected services (dateSharedService, doctorSharedService).